# undeclared identifier 'setfscreation' AOSP

Tags: android, linux, build, android-source, selinux

I'm trying to build AOSP but I get this strange error. It's about SELinux module i think. Anyone of you guys have ever encountered this kind of problem?

```
[ 65% 22783/34570] target thumb C++: updater <= bootable/recovery/updater/install.cpp
FAILED: /bin/bash -c "(PWD=/proc/self/cwd /usr/bin/ccache prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/clang-2690385/bin/clang++ -I system/extras/ext4_utils -I external/e2fsprogs/misc -I bootable/recovery/updater/.. -I /home/build/dfrascari/android7/AOSP/out/target/product/generic/obj/PACKAGING/updater_extensions_intermediates/ -I bootable/recovery/updater -I /home/build/dfrascari/android7/AOSP/out/target/product/generic/obj/EXECUTABLES/updater_intermediates -I /home/build/dfrascari/android7/AOSP/out/target/product/generic/gen/EXECUTABLES/updater_intermediates -I libnativehelper/include/nativehelper \$(cat /home/build/dfrascari/android7/AOSP/out/target/product/generic/obj/EXECUTABLES/updater_intermediates/import_includes) -isystem system/core/include -isystem system/media/audio/include -isystem hardware/libhardware/include -isystem hardware/libhardware_legacy/include -isystem hardware/ril/include -isystem libnativehelper/include -isystem frameworks/native/include -isystem frameworks/native/opengl/include -isystem frameworks/av/include -isystem frameworks/base/include -isystem /home/build/dfrascari/android7/AOSP/out/target/product/generic/obj/include -isystem bionic/libc/arch-arm/include -isystem bionic/libc/include -isystem bionic/libc/kernel/uapi -isystem bionic/libc/kernel/common -isystem bionic/libc/kernel/uapi/asm-arm -isystem bionic/libm/include -isystem bionic/libm/include/arm -c    -fno-exceptions -Wno-multichar -msoft-float -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -Wa,--noexecstack -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-short-enums -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -DANDROID -fmessage-length=0 -W -Wall -Wno-unused -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Werror=date-time -DNDEBUG -g -Wstrict-aliasing=2 -DNDEBUG -UDEBUG  -D__compiler_offsetof=__builtin_offsetof -Werror=int-conversion -Wno-reserved-id-macro -Wno-format-pedantic -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -fcolor-diagnostics -nostdlibinc  -target arm-linux-androideabi    -target arm-linux-androideabi -Bprebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/arm-linux-androideabi/bin    -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wsign-promo  -Wno-inconsistent-missing-override -nostdlibinc  -target arm-linux-androideabi   -mthumb -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing  -fno-rtti -DUSE_EXT4 -Wno-unused-parameter -fpie -D_USING_LIBCXX -std=gnu++14  -Werror=int-to-pointer-cast -Werror=pointer-to-int-cast  -Werror=address-of-temporary -Werror=null-dereference -Werror=return-type    -MD -MF /home/build/dfrascari/android7/AOSP/out/target/product/generic/obj/EXECUTABLES/updater_intermediates/install.d -o /home/build/dfrascari/android7/AOSP/out/target/product/generic/obj/EXECUTABLES/updater_intermediates/install.o bootable/recovery/updater/install.cpp ) && (cp /home/build/dfrascari/android7/AOSP/out/target/product/generic/obj/EXECUTABLES/updater_intermediates/install.d /home/build/dfrascari/android7/AOSP/out/target/product/generic/obj/EXECUTABLES/updater_intermediates/install.P; sed -e 's/#.*//' -e 's/^[^:]*: *//' -e 's/ *\\\\\$//' -e '/^\$/ d' -e 's/\$/ :/' < /home/build/dfrascari/android7/AOSP/out/target/product/generic/obj/EXECUTABLES/updater_intermediates/install.d >> /home/build/dfrascari/android7/AOSP/out/target/product/generic/obj/EXECUTABLES/updater_intermediates/install.P; rm -f /home/build/dfrascari/android7/AOSP/out/target/product/generic/obj/EXECUTABLES/updater_intermediates/install.d )"
bootable/recovery/updater/install.cpp:165:13: error: use of undeclared identifier 'setfscreatecon'
            setfscreatecon(secontext);
            ^
bootable/recovery/updater/install.cpp:172:13: error: use of undeclared identifier 'setfscreatecon'
            setfscreatecon(NULL);
            ^
2 errors generated.
[ 65% 22783/34570] target thumb C++: updater <= bootable/recovery/updater/blockimg.cpp
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
make: *** [ninja_wrapper] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
sudo apt install libselinux1-dev
```

But probably your system is not configured for AOSP build. You can execute that command

```
sudo apt-get install git-core gnupg flex bison gperf build-essential zip curl zlib1g-dev gcc-multilib g++-multilib libc6-dev-i386 lib32ncurses5-dev x11proto-core-dev libx11-dev lib32z-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libxml2-utils xsltproc unzip
```

And follow all other instructions from https://source.android.com/setup/build/initializing